# What is the maximum supported I2C mode in the FS32K146?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, nxp

In the S32K146 [user-manual](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/S32K-RM.pdf) guide, it is mentioned as High-Speed mode is not supported by this device. (Page 1481).
[image]
But in the coming section of the user-manual it is mentioned as device support HS mode (page 1483).

[image]
Both seems bit contradictory for me. What are the I2C modes supported by S32K146? And what is the maximum speed of I2C clock frequency?

Comment: You should probably contact the vendor